# Changing Spring Version in pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm working on a Spring Boot project. Initially, I started with Spring **3.0.0**, but the project specification requires the use of version **2.x** instead.

I tried to manually change this in line 8 of pom.xml but am now getting an error. How do I correct this?

> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains
> compatible versions of the classes
> org.springframework.plugin.core.config.PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar
> and org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lochlann</groupId>
    <artifactId>assignment2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>assignment2</name>
    <description>assignment2</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version> <!-- ? after init - needed to manually add version??? -->
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>  <!-- ? after init - this was miss-spelled???? -->
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try changing java version also. And give screenshot about your error!

Comment: Use `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` instead of a direct dependency on `hateoas` that will give you the right compatible version and dependencies. Your version is incompatible (and it uses another project as well, pulling in an incompatible version). Unrelated remove the `version` tag from the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` that is already managed by Spring Boot parent.